# Suppress TypeScript errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Is it possible to suppress errors in Visual Studio (when working with TypeScript)?

Specifically I'd like to suppress the `is declared but never used`-error. When debugging I need to comment out some code every once in a while, but Visual Studio refuses to build the project if I have declared a function I'm not using.

Why is that an error to begin with? Shouldn't it be a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a csproj -file, you can get rid of the `is declared but never used` -error by removing the line

`<TypeScriptNoUnusedLocals>True</TypeScriptNoUnusedLocals>`

or changing it to

`<TypeScriptNoUnusedLocals>False</TypeScriptNoUnusedLocals>`

Some other settings for suppressing errors:

`<TypeScriptAllowUnreachableCode>True</TypeScriptAllowUnreachableCode>`
`<TypeScriptNoUnusedParameters>False</TypeScriptNoUnusedParameters>`
`<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>`

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `tsconfig.json` file, more information here:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

It might take some time to get it configured the way you have your project configured now, but there is a setting to not error when there are unused locals:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noUnusedLocals": false
    }
}
```

There are also a couple other settings, `noUnusedParameters`, `allowUnsedLabels` and `allowUnreachableCode` which may help you.

The schema for the JSON file is available here: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Visual Studio should know that the JSON file is a `tsconfig` file and provide you with IntelliSense information from that schema file.

Comment: I couldn't get Visual Studio to work properly with the tsconfig.json. For example the Solution Explorer wasn't working at all. But your answer caused me go through the cproj -file again, and the I found the offending setting there, so thanks again.

Comment: @skoll no problem!  If you end up finding more problems, you can report them on Github to Microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript